# How to wrap a tag around a text inside a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="myclass">Hello everybody!</div>
```

Then I want to wrap a `<p>` tag around the text to have this:

```
<div class="myclass"><p>Hello everybody!</p></div>
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

I tried this:

```
$('.myclass').text().wrap('p');
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

```
$('.myclass').wrapInner('<p></p>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y8Es/)

Comment: thanks, and how can I remove the <p> tag for example if I leave the mouse ( if I use hover function ) ..

Comment: @palaѕн The demo you have given in the above comment is not having a proper markup. You simply encapsulated the text inside the div tag. But it should have been encapsulated within <p> tag. Right.?

Comment: @palaѕн OP just asked you to remove the <p> tag from that Div. I said that your input markup doesn't have any <p> tag at all. Sorry if i'v confused you. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.. Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y8Es/4/) to remove <p> tag using the [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
        $(function(){
            $('.myclass').wrapInner('<p></p>');
        })
```

REFERENCE :

http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

**Alternative**

```
        $(function(){
            var txt = '<p>' + $('.myclass').text() + '</p>'; 
            $('.myclass').html(txt);
        })
```

Again to remove p tag

```
        $(function(){
            var txt = $('.myclass').text();
            $('.myclass').html(txt);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

A Different approach,

```
$('.myclass').html('<p>' + $('.myclass').text() + '</p>');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7y8Es/1/)

To unwrap the tag you simply do like this,

```
$(".myclass").html($('.myclass > p').text());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7y8Es/3/)